# Use .NET DLL on multiple platforms

Tags: c#, android, ios, dll, monogame

I am using C# to create a game using MonoGame which I wish to use on multiple platforms (which I know MonoGame can do).

Is there a way to create a .dll in C# and load it from other operating systems (preferably iOS, Android and MacOS) without recompiling the library? I am prepared to write a "loader" application for each platform, but would not like to rewrite the entire project.

I'm hoping there is a way to load functions from a .net dll (i.e. load the game) on these platforms without using paid products such as MonoTouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the .NET/Mono Assemblies all get compiled to CIL Code which is an ECMA Standard.

However, you still have to program your game in a way that it do not depend on OS specifics.

- Don't refer to certain .NET Assemblies (i.e. No WCF, cause it has only limited WCF support, no WPF at all, no WWF)
- Don't refer to OS specific DLLs (i.e. no P/Invokes to kernel32.dll etc.
- Don't use OS specific pathes or use preprocessor directives to make OS Specific code (yes, this will require recompile and you probably won't get around this easily)

Threading on Mono has some catches, so you will probably have to make platform specific code using preprocessor directives.

Honestly, I don't see a problem with having to recompile your code, if it's clearly written it's just a matter of adding a new project to your solution file and setting the preprocessor flags. Then all you have to do is compile the solution and have multiple DLLs in your bin folder. No one ever said you have to rewrite the complete project (unless the project is already finished and has any of the dependency mentioned up there), which in this case... it's your own fault for not having to think about it **before** starting development.

You'll just have to deploy your Apps (on iOS etc.) with the required Mono Runtime. And for this you will probably need something like Xamarin or wire up your own Mono runtime

Reference links: 
http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility
http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: With the recompiling, I would prefer not to but it seems that I'll have to. But the use of Xamarin (a commercial product) is an issue.

Comment: Could a better solution be to have the app run and load and interpret something such as JavaScript? This may allow for more code reuse

Comment: It's usually not a big problem, 98% of the code will work. But for example you should not write your game against .NET 4.5 API, because Mono doesn't support it yet fully (especially the new async stuff). 

Also special folders may not work correctly on mobiles, if the mono library is not complied for it. Some special folders do not exist for windows. You can get an rough idea on this page what works and what not (.NET Framework compatibility)

http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: You could wire up your own run-time without Xamarin but it would probably take a lot more effort and cost than just buying a Xamarin license. That's why people buy it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the Xamarin-Framework. But you always have to recompile your project.
[Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

> on these platforms without using paid products such as MonoTouch.

This will be difficult.

Comment: MonoTouch is Xamarin.iOS. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Also, this may be completely wrong, but I've heard of P/Invoke which can be used to call dll functions.
Could this work from another platform?

Comment: Other Platforms doens't have DLLs like Microsoft. So i think, that doesn't twork

Comment: Although I have noticed that in iOS apps created by Unity, there are DLL files inside the .app folder. I don't know how they are being used, but this indicates that there may be some way to call DLL functions in iOS.

Comment: Unity ships it's own mono runtime (a libmono.so & libmono_proxy.so for Android for example) which will execute the Mono/.NET assemblies. On Windows 8 & Win8Phone/WinRT, unity can run mono, so they have to run the .NET Assembly on the Win8/Win8Phone/WinRT .NET Framework. 

And for this one needs preprocessor directives (i.e `#if FXCORE45` or something like that). And unity requires recompile too for each platform. But if you have platform specific code (i.e. iOS game center integration then you **need** preprocessor directives, because iOS Gamecenter is not available on other platforms)

Comment: Just in case, it should me noted that Unity runs a very old version of Mono (2.6, current one is 2.10.8) which mostly supports .NET up to 3.5 fully and parts of 4.0.

Comment: My reason for not wanting to recompile is that I want to build iOS apps from windows and not use a Mac with each game build

Comment: It's not possible to compile iOS Apps from Windows. The tools required to make an iOS app are only available on a MacOS (i.e. XCode, which is the envirnoment iOS Apps use). Even with Unity3D this is not possible. For Unity3D you will need a mac + App Store Dev access + compile it under iOS. 

Also Unity3D on iOS and Android uses AoT compliing vs Jit Compiling on Desktop and Webplayer for performance reasons. This alone already forces a recompile, not considering the platform dependent code